# Input File verificar que el arhivo que estan subiendo ya esta en la carpeta

Tags: php, input-file

Este es mi codigo en php para el input file que tengo, guarda o mueve los videos subidos en una carpeta, la gran duda que tengo ahora es como verifico que ya este un video en esa carpeta... que si la persona si sube  un video y va a volverlo hacer no la deje o saque alguna advertencia. ante mano muchas gracias !!! espero que me puedan ayudar

```
<?php 
    $name= $_FILES['file1']['name'];
    $tmp_name= $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES["file1"]["size"];
    if (isset($name)) {
        if (empty($name)) {
            echo "Please choose a file";
        } if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "archivos/$name")) {
            echo 'Subida completada';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la función [file_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php) puedes comprobar si existe un archivo con un nombre en concreto en el directorio que quieras. La idea sería que lo implementaras de una forma similar a la siguiente:

```
<?php 
    $name= $_FILES['file1']['name'];
    $tmp_name= $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES["file1"]["size"];
    if (isset($name)) {
        if (empty($name)) {
            echo "Please choose a file";
        } else if (file_exists("archivos/$name")) { // Comprobación
            echo "Este archivo ya existe";
        } else if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "archivos/$name")) {
            echo 'Subida completada';
        }
    }
?>
```

En el código he añadido un `else` en tu último `if`, ya que en el código que has compartido, aunque salte el primer error de *"Please choose a file"*, el archivo se subirá de igual modo. Además, añadir a modo de recomendación que tu código si está completo tiene muchas vulnerabilidades de seguridad.

Comment: Si funciono aunque se subio de igual forma el archivo, bueno esta con un bar progress por eso lo note y muchas  gracias tendre muy en cuenta la recomendaión!

Comment: @HemersonOsorio ¿Te sale en mensaje de "Este archivo ya existe"? Si es así, te puedo asegurar que no se ha subido (si has usado este mismo código). Haz una cosa, sube 2 archivos diferentes pero con el mismo nombre, y luego entra al archivo y mira cuál está guardado

Comment: Tienes razón, es que primero esta el JS del  bar progress y ese ya abre el php "ajax.open("POST", "subir.php");" imagino que por  eso se visualiza la barra... disculpa  molestarte tanto pero  no hay forma de hacer este metodo en JS por decir ahora tengo JS  verificar el tamaño del archivo ja y muchas gracias por la ayuda en serio!!

Comment: @HemersonOsorio Sí que se puede pero es muy complejo y al ser desde el lado del cliente solo te serviría para mostrar errores y demás, ya que todo lo que se hace del lado del cliente es manipulable. Pero daría para otra pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que consultar si existe el fichero donde esta almacenado tu archivo, $ruta = /carpeta/carpeta/... 
luego vas a concatenar el nombre de tu archivo, prueba el sgte codigo.

```
 if (file_exists($ruta.'/'.$name)) {
        echo "The file $name exists";
    }else {
        echo "The file $name does 
                               not exists";
    }
```

Comment: De igual forma funciono aunque si subio el archivo, bueno esta con un bar progress por eso lo note :(